# Cost Function derivation and determination of optimal value

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization

I want to derive equation(s) for a cost function and then to get optimal value from cost function for parameter 'P' used in the algorithm, i have outputs generated from algorithm that are user service time(delay) and number of conflicts generated.
Over internet, i have seen Microsoft excel where 'solver' Add-inn is used to get optimum (Min or Max value) but they all start with cost functions equations already in hand.
My question is

1. How can i derive cost function equation? Do i need output from algorithm for different parameter value 'P' or else.
   I have output available from algorithm for different values of 'P', listed below:

[image]

Can any one tell me how to get cost function equations given that conflicts and Delay should be minimized and have constraint that `0<=P<=1`
Using Excel and gnuplot, when tried to do linear regression with 'P' (dependent) and conflicts (independent) variables, i got this trend line with equation, `y=-9206.43x + 10495` ,shown in figure below. But here linear regression did't produce matching trend and its quite different, is there any other regression technique, i can try?

[image]

Comment: What are the dependent and independent variables here? In general you have to assume a function which you then fit.

Comment: Conflicts and Delay are dependent variables and 'P' is independent.

Comment: As I said you have to assume first a type of function before you can make curve fitting.

Comment: I can drop Delay variable and then there is only one dependent variable (Conflicts) with 'P' as independent variable. Now how i can get cost function and then how i can get optimal value for 'P'?

Comment: Make a graph and look if the relation between P and Conflicts may linear, exponential, polynomial, etc.

Comment: Wait a moment: "Conflicts and Delay are dependent variables and 'P' is independent" You have two dependent variables and only one independent variable? Usually it is the other way round.

Comment: @callculus you are correct, i mistakenly has written opposite, Still waiting , if any one can help me on this.